# Add field manager to application Main screen in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am working with a BlackBerry application for OS 5.0 and later.  The application has one screen which displays at the top of screen a `Next` and a `Previous` button. and list field also display in this screen at bottom of these both button

When i click on `NEXT Button` and `Previous Button` my List will be updated display data..

When i click on NEXT/PREVIOUS Button i have to display small VerticalfieldManager at the center of the screen with Label "Please wait ..." so after design this screen how can we add more field manager in over the another manager ?

Is there any way to display that Field at the application MainScreen like iPhone AppDelegate screen?

```
btnState.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
        {   vfm_Middle.add(lblPleasewait);
            popup = new PopupScreen(manager);
            Thread thread = new Thread()
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Updatelistfield();
                        stop();
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    super.run();
                }

                public synchronized void stop() 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() 
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            //popup.delete(vfm_Main);
                            //popup.deleteAll();
                            //vfm_Main.delete(lblPleasewait);
                            //lblPleasewait.setText(null);

                        }
                    });
                }
            };

            thread.start();

        }
    });
```

Comment: @vijay.jangid07 i have not implemented "Please wait..." manger code  .. rather that screen other coding implement successfull .. i have no idea how to put manager over manager ?

Comment: You first have to implement and then ask question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way of doing that is with a blocking dialog. In BB API this can be done as follows:

```
VerticalFieldManager manager = new VerticalFieldManager();
manager.add(new LabelField("Please Wait..."));
Screen popup = new PopupScreen(manager);
//Show the pop-up the same way you push a regular screen
```

This has the advantage of blocking the GUI: if the user pushes the menu or esc key it doesn't have any effect.

If you want to do it in your screen without dialogs, then you can add an empty `VerticalFieldManager` which you can fill with a label when the message has to be shown. This way, instead of updating the entire screen, only the Manager is refreshed. But then you should write the logic to not letting the user push any button or menu key (or ignoring key press).

Comment: i have implement this code to my Next Button click event but i cant show any "manager" ... is it working ob Button click event ?

Comment: its working in verticalFieldManager of that screen . and how to remove this "popup" ?

Comment: i can also click on other field of that screen ? how to disable during popup visible ?

Comment: To show and remove the popup just do `pushScreen` and `popScreen` as if it were a regular screen. Be careful to do this in the event thread (use `UiApplication.invokeLater` or `UiApplication.invokeandWait`). So prior loading data show the popup, then load the list field, then remove the popup from screen.

Comment: please checkmy updated code ... in run() method i had tried popup.close(); but popup cant close and m getting error :IIlegalstateException

Comment: In the `run` method, there's no need of that try catch (unless `Updatelistfield` throws exceptions, but if that is the case then you should catch `Exception` instead of `InterruptedException`. Anyway, the closing of the popup should be performed the last thing in the `run` method. For instance, inside the `stop` method, BUT change its name (stop exists in Thread, but is deprecated,unsafe and final) and quit the synchronized. The sentence could be `Application.getApplication().popscreen(popup);`

Comment: Also quit the call to `super.run()` as it serves no purpose.

Comment: i cant implement this Application.getApplication().popscreen(popup); . i cant access popsreen() method.

Comment: Sorry, actually is `UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(popup)`.

Comment: i already tried this also .. is it right in invokeletter method ?

Comment: Yes, as that method runs the runnable on the "Event thread", which is the only thread accesing the GUI in a safe manner. If you try to modify the GUI in other thread, it throws an exception.

Comment: when i delete please wait Label and replace  Updatelistfield(); to Thread.sleep(3000); than everythig is work fine ...but when place this method Updatelistfield(); getting error ..in this method xml parsing is done ...

Comment: You should try-catch that method. Many things could go bad (serializing, connection, parsing, etc).